# Python subprocess directing data to standard intput

Tags: c++, python, windows, python-2.7

I have a C++ program on Windows that reads characters in from standard input.  I want to write a Python script that opens this C++ program and then have the script write to the programs standard input.

I can successfully create the subprocess in Python and read from standard out.  However, the program fails to receive anything from standard in by the Python script.  The program uses ReadConsole() to read from standard in and it repeatedly returns error code 6 (Invalid Handle) even though GetStdHandle() returns without error.

Here is the programs code:

```
char buffer[GIDE_BUFFER_SIZE];
HANDLE hConsole_c = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD chars_read = 0;

if(hConsole_c == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
    gide_printf(LOG_ERR,"ERROR: INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE for stdout: %d.", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
    keyboard_handler_running = false;
    main_thread_running = false;
    }
else if( hConsole_c == NULL)
    {
    gide_printf(LOG_ERR,"ERROR: Unable to get handle to standard output.");
    fflush(stdout);
    keyboard_handler_running = false;
    main_thread_running = false;
    }

gide_printf(LOG_DEBUG,"keyboard_listener thread started.");

Sleep(500); //sleep to give time for everything to come up.
print_menu();
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

//reads characters from console after enter is pressed.
//enter key adds CR and a LF so it adds two chars to all output.
while(keyboard_handler_running)
    {
    if( ReadConsole( hConsole_c, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &chars_read, NULL ) == 0)
        {
        gide_printf(LOG_ERR,"ERROR: Reading from console failed: %d.", GetLastError());
        ErrorHandler("blah");
        continue;
        }
    gide_printf(LOG_DEBUG,"Read %d chars from console.", chars_read);
.
.
.
.
```

Here is the Python Script:

```
import time
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

print '0'
proc = subprocess.Popen('program.exe', stdout=None, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
time.sleep(2)

print '1'
proc.stdin.write('xtyasmdmdjmdhjmdmjdmjd\n')
time.sleep(2)

print '2'
proc.stdin.close()
proc.stdout.close()
proc.kill()
```

MSDN mentions the following:  *Although ReadConsole can only be used with a console input buffer handle, ReadFile can be used with other handles (such as files or pipes). ReadConsole fails if used with a standard handle that has been redirected to be something other than a console handle.*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I"m wondering if that has something to do with it.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to go about doing this, or a better way to do with with Python, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::cin.read()`?  (There may be something - my Windows coverage is patchy these days / prefer Linux).

Comment: Nope. that doesn't fix it.  cin.getline(str,buffer_size) will repeatedly return 0 characters.  So its probably failing in a similar manner.  Its just less informing abut why its failing.

Comment: Sounds like the stream's in error, unreadable and/or EOF state.  Anyway, to confirm whether the problem is on the python or C++ side, you could check whether you can `type input_file | your_app` and read it properly from a non-keyboard pipe... if so then it's python.  If not, `std::string line; while (getline(std::cin, line)) { ... }` is the normal way to do line-by-line parsing of standard input.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround which gives some insight into the nature of the problem.  I'm working in Visual Studio using a Windows Console project.  I created a new "blank project" and instead of using the Windows API of ReadConsole() I used the C++ API of std::cin.getline(). That fixes the problem.

Once again, it isn't a solution as much as workaround. But it indicates that the problem seems to be something with the Windows API or Visual Studio project settings.